# CentOS7- Why able to ping when network services is down?

Tags: linux, centos, networking

Please advice below questions:

Under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`, there are 2 configuration interface files (ifcfg-enp0s3 and ifcfg-lo) as shown in [network-scripts content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVyzz.jpg)

I type `ifconfig` and it shows me lo, eth0 and eth1 as shown in [result of command ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8awL.jpg)

**Question 1: Why host only adapter (eth1) is missing in network-scripts?**

**Question 2:  Why ifconfig is showing as eth when it's enp0s in network-scripts?**

I used `systemctl status network` and `systemctl status NetworkManager` to confirm both services are down.

**Question 3: Why I was able to ping google when all network services are down?**

Network status is down as shown in [status of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQvK.jpg)

NetworkManager status is down as shown in [status of Network Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFo7U.jpg)

Able to ping Goole as shown in [able to ping Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TJsB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your "status of network" provides no details about why something failed in a systemd script. ifconfig shows them as up and you presumably have a default route, so ping works.
Network manager isn't a real-time controller, and it usually gets in the way if you want to do anything the least bit odd, so its status isn't useful.